# opencv imread/imwrite loss the color

Tags: opencv

I use the sample code to read/write an jpg file, but loss the color.

```
import sys
fn1,fn2  = sys.argv[1:3]
import numpy as np, cv2

img1 = cv2.imread(fn1, 0)
vis = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cv2.imwrite(fn2, vis)
```

can you help me find the program.

Comment: I think that this script raise an error, if youu want to open a jpg file and then write its gray converted to another file use `cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY` instead of non-existing `cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR`

Comment: use `cv.BGR2GRAY` instead of non-existing `cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR`, and change `cv2.imread(fn1,0)` to `cv2.imread(fn1)`

Answer (score 0):

use this code instead and find differences

```
import sys
fn1,fn2  = sys.argv[1:3]
import numpy as np, cv2, cv

img1 = cv2.imread(fn1)
vis = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imwrite(fn2, vis)
```

Answer (score 0):

By default an open image file is `BGR` format. but you are trying to convert it from `Gray` to `BGR`.

```
// this conversion is incorrect 
vis = cv2.cvtColor(img1, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cv2.imwrite(fn2, vis)
```

if you do not want any conversion then remove this line `cv2.cvtColor(...)`. try just.

> img1 = cv2.imread(fn1, 0)
>   cv2.imwrite(fn2, img1)